# how to create inside curve using relative or linear layout in android

Tags: android, xml, material-components-android, android-shapedrawable

How to create this in android layout i tried many ways but i didn't found any method to do this

[image: Like this image]

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="100000dp" />
<solid android:color="#5fb0c9" />
<stroke
    android:width="-5dip"
    android:color="#3da8c9" />
<padding
    android:bottom="-4dp"
    android:left="-4dp"
    android:right="-4dp"
    android:top="-4dp" />
```

Comment: Is it ok to add [edge](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/TMDb-Paging/blob/master/app/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi/edge.png) to your view?

Comment: will tht look like this? @Ali

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`MaterialCardView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md) and apply a [**`ShapeAppearanceModel`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md).

Something like:

```
  TriangleEdgeTreatment edgeTreatment = new TriangleEdgeTreatment(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cutout_size),true);

  cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
      .toBuilder()
      .setTopEdge(edgeTreatment)
      .build());
```

[image]

Comment: i want to to that in xml file only